# "Customer information #number" option appeared for sellecting shipping address?

Tags: 8, commerce

After implementing ShippingOrderProcessor:

https://gist.github.com/jsacksick/fde031197df92236ef5a916775e17a2e

which I needed to show shipping costs on cart and order overview page (order summary block) on order information page, shipping section, drop-down for selecting existing address or creating new one now has one extra item and it's default? Options now look like:

```
Some street 225.             -> ok, existing address from address book
Customer information #498    -> this just appeared, want to remove it
+ Enter a new address.       -> also ok, option for adding new address
```

Inside same section for selecting billing address I don't get that "Customer information #498" option, but just existing addresses to choose from or "+ Enter a new address" which is how it suppose to look.

Drop-down html looks like:

```
<select class="available-profiles ..." name="shipping_information[shipping_profile][select_address]">
    <option value="183">Some street 233</option>
    <option value="_original">Customer information #498</option>
    <option value="_new" selected="selected">+ Enter a new address</option>
</select>
```

If I figured it well that ShippingOrderProcessor is creating an dummy user profile needed for adding shipment, that dummy (empty) appears as this extra option.

I managed to removed it by hacking drupal/web/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/order/src/Plugin/Commerce/InlineForm/CustomerProfile.php
but I'm proud of that solution.

What would be the proper way to remove this dummy profile? Maybe to delete it somehow inside `hook_user_login()`?

Comment: It's used in form validation to see if the address is different, [see here](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce_shipping/-/blob/8.x-2.x/src/Form/ShipmentForm.php#L263), so I don't think it's a good idea to remove it.

Comment: There is [a test](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce_shipping/-/blob/8.x-2.x/tests/src/FunctionalJavascript/ProfileFieldCopyTest.php#L520) that's suppose to check that it's gone. So seems like there is a bug.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me also. It shouldn't appear on front-end.

Comment: Opened the bug ticket here: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping/issues/3179099

Comment: @NoSssweat on Drupal slack support channel jsacksick told me that this is not a bug and this option can be turned off by disabling profile copying from pane settings. But I have no idea where those settings are?

Comment: Updated the question with new founding and closed the issue ticket.